# Hierarchy parent child for 20.000 rows

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:[image]

I am able to create indent(level) by using the below code so it gives me what I need for a specific parentCode but there are 20.000 rows in the table.

```
;WITH items AS (
SELECT distinct a.Code,ParentCode,0 AS Indent       
FROM tblReport a
WHERE 
ParentCode = '71' 
UNION ALL
SELECT  i.Code,i.ParentCode, Indent + 1
FROM tblReport i
INNER JOIN items itms ON itms.Code = i.ParentCode
)
SELECT distinct Code, ParentCode,Indent FROM items
```

[image]

If I set parentCode to NULL then the query takes too long. It runs for hours and still doesn't return the data. Is there any other way that I can achieve this? I can do it in server side or client side so it doesn't matter if you have a solution in javascript or in c# or in SQL.

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good. The following index should improve the performance of your query:

```
create index ix1 on tblReport (parentCode, Code);
```

Comment: SQL Server v17.8 and I have already created the index. It doesn't help.

Comment: Does the graph have cycles in it? If it does, your query will run forever...

Comment: I don't know. If it does what should I do?